# Document created but response is null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having two issues with my code. Firstly, I always get the error: "A website with this name already exists" even despite the logs telling me a site as just created. This is probably because my response is null. Secondly, I do not know how to return `documentId` from `createWebsite` back to `onConfirmButtonClick()` as a result so I can use it for further processing. Any ideas of what I can do to resolve this?

In component:

```
 onConfirmButtonClick() {
    this.websiteService.createWebsite(this.websiteName).then(result => {
      if(result) {
        this.toastrService.success('Your website has been created.');
        this.activeModal.close();
      } else {
        this.toastrService.error('A website with this name already exists.');
      }
    });
  }
```

In service:

```
  async createWebsite(name) {
    return this.afs.collection('websites', (ref) => ref.where('name', '==', name).limit(1)).get().subscribe(websites => {
      if(websites.size == 0) {
        const documentId = this.afs.createId();
        const documentPath = `websites/${ documentId }`;
        const documentRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(documentPath);
        this.logger.debug(`Created a website at: '/${ documentPath }'`);
        return documentRef.set({name: name}, { merge: true });
      } else {
        this.logger.debug(`A website with the name '${name}' already exists`);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In service do the following:

```
createWebsite(name) {
    return this.afs.collection('websites', (ref) => ref.where('name', '==', name).limit(1)).get();
  }
```

This will return an observable, then in the component subscribe to that observable.:

```
onConfirmButtonClick() {
    this.websiteService.createWebsite(this.websiteName).subscribe(websites => {
      if(websites.size == 0) {
        const documentId = this.afs.createId();
        const documentPath = `websites/${ documentId }`;
        const documentRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(documentPath);
        this.logger.debug(`Created a website at: '/${ documentPath }'`);
        documentRef.set({name: name}, { merge: true });
        this.toastrService.success('Your website has been created.');
        this.activeModal.close()
      } else {
        this.logger.debug(`A website with the name '${name}' already exists`);
      }
   });
  }
```

Then you will have the `documentId` inside the component, I'm not sure what `result` is..there is no indication in the whole code that you are using `resolve` to return anything from a `Promise`

Comment: I'm glad, that's great!